# XMLHttpRequest cannot load: Request doesn't pass access control check

Tags: angularjs, node.js, http-headers

I am trying to post data to my node server running on http://localhost:3000/. Here is my client side AngularJS code:

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  var app = angular.module('myApp');

  function SuggestController ($scope, $http) {

    var onResponse = function(response){
      $scope.responseMsg = response.data;
      console.log(data);
    };

    var onError = function(err){
      $scope.error = err;
    };

    $scope.suggest = function(){

      var new = $.param({
        sS: $scope.Source,
        dD: $scope.Destination
      });

      var config = {
        headers : {
          // 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8',
          //'crossDomain' : 'true',
          //'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' : true
        }
      };

      $http.post("http://localhost:3000/",nRoute, config).
        then(onResponse, onError);
    };
  }

  app.controller('SuggestController', ['$scope', '$http', SuggestController])

}());
```

In my NodeJS file, I added these lines of code:

```
app.post('/', function(req, res) {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods' , 'POST');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers' , 'Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token');
  res.setHeader('Content-Type' , 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
  console.log(req);
  res.send("Thanks for the Contribution\n");
})
```

But I am getting this message:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:3000/. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

How do I fix this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28677773/my-client-side-cors-really-not-working-in-angular-controller-pls-help-me-tim

Comment: This is My Post Buddy Take a look it may help you .. Use CORS Plugin that Helps at the same time the Headers you are Using are Need to Be Used in NODEJS .. angular is having diff Syntax .. check my post it may helps Good Luck !

Comment: now getting this
SyntaxError: Unexpected token T

Comment: can you plz post your compete error ?

Comment: i've adde 
`var cors = require('cors');
var app = express();

app.use(cors());`
to my nodejs file
it is now showing 
TypeError: invalid parameter format

Comment: Update Your Headers :- res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'OPTIONS,GET,POST,PUT,DELETE');
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With");

Comment: I think you Didn't Go Through My Post ...  server side Nodejs you need to use cors , client side i have some code use that .. which injects httpProvider

Comment: I Edited with proper code try that .. i have been working with that configuration ..from long time

Comment: Thanks for ur help...problem solved :D 
I am trying to post some data to the server . In server console it prints undefinded 
`app.post('/', function(req, res) {
 res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Method', 'POST');
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With");
    res.setHeader('Content-Type' , 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
    console.log(req.data);
  res.json(req.data); 

})`